# How to prove fn convergence in measure to f

Tags: real-analysis

If any subsequence $\{f_{n'}\}$of $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{f_{n'_k}\}$ which convergence to  $f$ almost everywhere then $f_n$ convergence to $f$ in measure.

How to prove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an infinite measure space this is false. Take $f=I_{(n,\infty )},f=0$ on the real line with Lebesgue measure. In a finite measure space convergence almost everywhere implies convergence in measure and if every subsequence of the sequence has  a subsequence converging in measure the whole sequence converges in measure. [ Just use proof by contradiction].

Comment: How to get the contradiction

Comment: Suppose $f_n$ does not in measure to $f$ and the given measure is a finite measure.  Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\mu \{x:|f_n (x)-f(x)| >\epsilon $ does not tend to $0$. This means there exists $\delta >0$ and integers $n_1<n_2<...$ such that $\mu \{x:|f_{n_k} (x)-f(x)| >\epsilon >\delta $ for all $k$. This clearly holds for any subsequence of $\{f_{n_k}\}$ also which implies that $f_{n_k}$ has no subsequence converging almost everywhere.